# Lucene : very slow NRT performance

Tags: c#, .net, lucene, lucene.net

I'm testing performance of NRT (near real time) searching in my application and i'm getting really odd results. I'm using this query as a sample to get all elements (the test set is very small so getting all elements shouldn't be an issue, this is 250 files getting indexed only, text files only, total index size= 1.5MB, the real set that i need to support is hundred of thouthands of files for a multi GB index)

Here's the sample query that is worrying me :

```
    public static List<IndexableItem> GetAllElements()
    {
        var qp = new Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29, "ProviderPath", analyzer);
        qp.AllowLeadingWildcard = true;
        var query = qp.Parse("*");

        var searcher = new Lucene.Net.Search.IndexSearcher(reader);
        List<IndexableItem> docs = new List<IndexableItem>();
        searcher.Search(query, new SimpleHitCollector(docId =>
        {
            docs.Add(reader.Document(docId).ToIndexable());
        }));
        return docs;
    }
```

As you can see it's pretty simple. The run time of this query is around 0.1 second while indexing isn't running, but if i have indexing running at the same time it goes up to . . . . 45 seconds or more!

The reader variable is a property defined as such :

```
    public static IndexReader reader 
    {
        get 
        {
            return writer.GetReader();
        }
    }
```

And writer  :

```
    static SearchIndexManager()
    {
        writer = new IndexWriter(FSDirectory.Open(@"C:\MyFolder"), analyzer, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
    }
```

The performance issue is within lucene for sure (it's within the hitcollector, takes up to 1 second between each docs.Add line). The ToIndexable cannot be the issue either (it's a trivial method and is completely not dependant on anything the indexer could use (disk io etc).

I'm fairly sure something is wrong there as obviously the goal of NRT isn't to get a 450X slowdown, any advice on where i should look for hints?

Some more information : I'm not calling optimise during the slowdowns, and "once in a while" i'll get a quick answer even when indexing but it seems pretty random when that happens. I do am calling commit once in a while (every 100 insertions).

Comment: If you are getting different response time with indexing running then I doubt you are in NRT.

Comment: Actually i found something pretty funky, if i remove all the calls to optimise / commit then the index stays in 1 file and keeps growing (this is expected behavior), but as soon as i launch a search, it splits as if a commit was getting forced, any clue what could cause this? Only the code i linked is getting called during a search and all it does is read using the reader provider by the writer as suggested to do NRT

Comment: Is this code appropriate to determine the performance of search concurrent with indexing? It will read every document in the index, and every field of each document; these may never be required in your application. Many scenarios only require up to say 50 search results. If the index is unchanged then documents may be in the I/O cache and available very fast (_first_ search is slower). If the index is changed then documents must be reloaded from disk - much slower than cache.

Comment: It is relevant yes, i do show 1000 of search results (it's not for a search engine paginated webapp, but for a full fledged search client with Advanced preview where people may want to have a look at quite a few 100s of results)

Comment: While I don't have a canonical answer for you, some suggestions. Your test code calls `IndexReader.Document` for every docID found by the search: try instead loading a list of _only_ docIDs (eg. another overload of `IndexSearcher.Search` returns `ScoreDoc[]`). Then load only enough `IndexableItem` objects to fill one screen (or two) of your advanced preview; test this to see if a "load on demand" strategy yields the required performance. If so you could _delay load_ the remaining `IndexableItem` objects, or implement the advanced preview as a virtual list, ie. "load on demand".

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, near-real-time search is intended for an index that has changed but changes have not yet been committed, and *no further changes will occur while searching*. This is the optimal usage of NRT, I don't mean that search is not possible *at the same time as* indexing. Searching or reading are suboptimal if they occur at the same time as indexing.

Consider the method `IndexReader.Reopen`. Its purpose is to obtain a fresh reader, if the index is changing or has changed since the old instance of `IndexReader` was obtained. Therefore if you continue using the old instance you might miss documents that you should find, and you are reading from a 'moving target', thus the slow performance.

You wrote:

> index stays in 1 file and keeps growing (this is expected behavior), but as soon as i launch a search, it splits as if a commit was getting forced

When you get an `IndexReader` from the `IndexWriter` it will flush any buffered changes - note this is not a commit.

Comment: NRT is meant so that you can search all the time and get data from the writer (wether it was commited or not), in my case there's no time to search when it's not indexing, i'm *always* indexing, 24/7, 365/year so NRT sounds like the obvious choice to provide somewhat recent changes.

Comment: Is there any way for it to not flush the changes to disk at all when i get the reader? (or would the reopen prevent that if i did that instead of getting another reader?)

Comment: Yes NRT is the obvious choice and the one I recommend. AFAIK there's no way to prevent the flush (if the index was changed) on calling `GetReader` or `Reopen`. I think the long delay is due to your frequent calls to `Commit`, which is a slow operation. To speed up search/show results, you could make fewer commits or avoid search that is concurrent with indexing, eg. delay indexing if search/show is active. To speed up search/show results, you could make fewer commits or avoid search that is concurrent with indexing, eg. delay indexing if search/show is active.

Comment: Also see [Near-real-time readers with Lucene's SearcherManager and NRTManager](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/11/near-real-time-readers-with-lucenes.html).

Comment: I'm finding the exact same result if i never commit, so commiting less won't help as the problem happens even if i don't commit at all. It's not possible to time searching / indexing separately, indexing always runs, and i can't control when people search and at what frequency, it's perfectly expected that there could be dozens of search at the same second and it performs just fine if i'm not indexing, but that's not an option

Comment: Also i don't think NRTManager is available to me (Lucene.net is at version 3.3.0 only, i think it's introduced in 3.5.0)

Comment: @RonanThibaudau Are you using the same thread or different threads to index and search?

Comment: Different threads, 1 thread is continuously indexing, N (up to 100, but the speed slowdown appear as soon as just 1 is active) threads listening to web requests & performing searches.

Comment: I found something that substantially upped performance, i will not post it as an answer as it doesn't fit the need i noted for the Bounty (detailed canonical answer) and it may not be a good solution but just hide the symptom deeper. The default max ram buffer is 16mb, setting it to 512 mb made searches barely slower when indexing than when not (a sample "list all elements" search that took 17 to 19 sec when not indexing, took 21 to 24 sec with this when indexing, vs 100+ sec when using the default 16 mb buffer)